How to check if a font exists with pdflatex?
When using XeTeX or LuaTex and fontspec, one can use \IfFontExistsTF{font name}{yes code}{no code}. What would be the best way to test if a font exists/can be loaded when fontspec is not available (like when using pdfTeX) (I am looking for the best solution even if it's not perfect)?

what do you want to do with the result? the reason I ask is because the answers suggest testing for the tfm, but getting from the existence of a particular tfm to a command which will successfully load a font in latex using latex's font-loading mechanisms is non-trivial.

@cfr yes I did wonder about making the same comment in my answer but as this seems to be one of a whole series of "pre-testing" questions from Vincent, I decided to just answer the question as asked. It is a good point though.

please see my edited answer below. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the original version which will not work for non-existent series/shapes. I've amended the code and (hopefully) it should work properly now. see the note at the bottom - you probably do not want to load nfssext-cfr unless you are using fonts which depend on it anyway, but you can easily add the couple of lines which are really needed here to get the necessary information. I don't know if there's a better way, but I couldn't find one when I asked here in June, so this is the method I used.

EDIT As egreg points out, the original version worked only for existential failures of encoding and family. The following detects existence failures for series and shapes, too. I don't like this way of doing it, but it is based on the best solution I could come up with for nfssext-cfr in the summer. I'm really not sure what I was thinking when I posted the original solution ....

The following doesn't test whether the TFM exists1, but whether the LaTeX font is defined. It takes as arguments the standard codes used to identify the four aspects of fonts defined by LaTeX's font selection mechanism: encoding, family, series and shape. It isn't necessary to know the name the font has (or would have).
\NewDocumentCommand \IfFontTF {mmmmmm}
{%
  \begingroup
  \fontencoding{#1}\fontfamily{#2}\fontseries{#3}\fontshape{#4}\try@load@fontshape
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax
    \endgroup
    #6%
  \else
    \fontencoding{#1}\fontfamily{#2}\fontseries{#3}\fontshape{#4}\selectfont
    \ifcsname exfs@fake@\curr@fontshape\endcsname
      \endgroup
      #6%
    \else
      \endgroup
      #5%
    \fi
  \fi
}

Then you can write, say,
\IfFontTF{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}{OT1/cmr/m/sc exists}{OT1/cmr/m/sc is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}{T1/clm/bx/n exists}{T1/clm/bx/n is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}{T1/clmx/bx/n exists}{T1/clmx/bx/n is non-existent.}


Because this test uses the standard LaTeX font selection details, you could use the same information to create a test which loads the font, if it exists, but does some other thing, if it doesn't.
    \NewDocumentCommand \FontIfExists {ommmm}
{%
  \begingroup
  \fontencoding{#2}\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}\try@load@fontshape
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax
    \endgroup
    \IfValueT{#1}{#1}%
  \else
    \fontencoding{#2}\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}\selectfont
    \ifcsname exfs@fake@\curr@fontshape\endcsname
      \endgroup
      \IfValueT{#1}{#1}%
    \else
      \endgroup
      \fontencoding{#2}\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}\selectfont
    \fi
  \fi
}

Then you can have something like
\IfFontTF{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}{OT1/cmr/m/sc exists}{OT1/cmr/m/sc is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}{T1/clm/bx/n exists}{T1/clm/bx/n is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}{T1/clmx/bx/n exists}{T1/clmx/bx/n is non-existent.}

\FontIfExists{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists[Oh, no!]{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists[Oh, dear!]{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists[Oops!]{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont


Complete code:
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727927/
\usepackage{nfssext-cfr}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \IfFontTF {mmmmmm}
{%
  \begingroup
  \fontencoding{#1}\fontfamily{#2}\fontseries{#3}\fontshape{#4}\try@load@fontshape
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax
    \endgroup
    #6%
  \else
    \fontencoding{#1}\fontfamily{#2}\fontseries{#3}\fontshape{#4}\selectfont
    \ifcsname exfs@fake@\curr@fontshape\endcsname
      \endgroup
      #6%
    \else
      \endgroup
      #5%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\NewDocumentCommand \FontIfExists {ommmm}
{%
  \begingroup
  \fontencoding{#2}\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}\try@load@fontshape
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax
    \endgroup
    \IfValueT{#1}{#1}%
  \else
    \fontencoding{#2}\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}\selectfont
    \ifcsname exfs@fake@\curr@fontshape\endcsname
      \endgroup
      \IfValueT{#1}{#1}%
    \else
      \endgroup
      \fontencoding{#2}\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}\selectfont
    \fi
  \fi
}
\let\ShowFont\curr@fontshape
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\IfFontTF{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}{OT1/cmr/m/sc exists}{OT1/cmr/m/sc is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}{T1/clm/bx/n exists}{T1/clm/bx/n is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clm}{bz}{n}{T1/clm/bz/n exists}{T1/clm/bz/n is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}{T1/clmx/bx/n exists}{T1/clmx/bx/n is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{T1}{clm}{bx}{blurb}{T1/clm/bx/blurb exists}{T1/clm/bx/blurb is non-existent.}

\IfFontTF{OT1}{cmr}{m}{blurb}{YES}{NO}

\FontIfExists{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists[Oh, no!]{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists[Oh, dear!]{T1}{clm}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont

\FontIfExists[Oops!]{T1}{clmx}{bx}{n}
\ShowFont


\FontIfExists[egreg says `no']{OT1}{cmr}{m}{blurb}
\ShowFont

\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}

Updated test cases:

Note that this test uses kernel macros with @s in them, which are supposed to be internal. However, as with most of LaTeX 2e, there are no suitable public interfaces (of which I'm aware), so packages etc. typically have to use internals.
The amended code also uses an internal macro from nfssext-cfr. If you don't want to use the package (which you probably don't), it should work to add
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hook_gput_code:nnn { cmd/wrong@fontshape/before } { . }
{
  \global\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let
  \expandafter \csname exfs@fake@ \curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

to the preamble after \makeatletter and remove the \usepackage{nfssext-cfr} line. You should then change exfs@ to vincent@ (or similar) throughout.
1Note that the existence of a TFM, <name>.tfm does not mean the existence of a usable LaTeX font, <name>, because <name>.tfm may not correspond to any defined font. ybvho8sr.tfm exists, but it would not make sense to try to load ybvho8sr. Rather, the TeX font defined by ybvho8sr.tfm is intended to be used only indirectly via one or more virtual fonts. However, if a font <name> is properly defined, there must be a TFM, <name>.tfm. So, given the name of a font, testing for the TFM can establish its existence (though not whether it is configured for LaTeX or whether there is a corresponding type1 or truetype font required by pdfTeX).

+1 for  answering the question that should have been asked not the one that was asked

@cfr I see \makeatletter ... \makeatother in the MCVE now. Maybe consider adding it to the shorter listings so they’ll work if copy-pasted in?

@Davislor that would be rather misleading since there are other things you'd have to add to get the code to work. and depending on where you're pasting the code, \makeatletter ... \makeatother may cause problems e.g. if you were to paste into a custom .sty file or to add it inside an existing \makeat... block or whatever. snippets are just for explanation: they aren't supposed to work standalone.

@cfr OK. Great answer!

@egreg thanks. I really don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the earlier version.

Could you describe a little bit more what the \hook_gput_code:nnn is doing if I'm unfamiliar with hooks?

Also what would be a version that would only test for encoding and family (as in "there exist at least one series/shape for this encoding/family")?

@Vincent it injects a marker based on font name every time the kernel fails to find the shape and series requested. it does this because the kernel creates a font with the requested shape and series even if no such shape/series is available. so once you've requested that shape/series, the font exists - it just may not have anything to do with the shape/series you asked for e.g. you asked for extra light condensed upright italic, but the actual font may be medium width regular weight upright. the only way I know to tell whether the requested font actually exists is to record all fake fonts.

@Vincent look for the fd file in that case. if you just want to know if there's a family (which is always for an encoding), just use a standard test for file existence. you don't need all this elaborate machinery for that. while it is possible for there to be fonts without fd files for pdflatex, the number of such fonts is absolutely negligible. looking for the fd will almost always tell you what you want to know and is far and away simpler than anything in my answer ;).


You can look for the tfm file with kpsewhich which does not need --shell-escapein the default configuration of texlive.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\IfTFMExistsTF{m}{%
  \begingroup\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar=\m@ne
  \expanded{\endgroup
  \edef\noexpand\tmp{\@@input{|kpsewhich #1.tfm}}}%
  \ifx\tmp\@empty
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


cmr10: \IfTFMExistsTF{cmr10}{yes}{no}

cmr42: \IfTFMExistsTF{cmr42}{yes}{no}

t5-qbkr: \IfTFMExistsTF{t5-qbkr}{yes}{no}

\end{document}

The nonsense at the start is to work around the end of file handling from the virtual file implied by the \input| syntax.

does that redefine \noexpand?

@cfr no it just executes \noexpand to disable the annoying end-of-file token that causes a "file ended" error if it is seem inside an edef.

I really shouldn't read lines of code in isolation ....

A more compact version with expl3:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\IfTFMExistsTF{mmm}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN {kpsewhich~#1.tfm} {\endlinechar=-1} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_tmpa_tl {#3} {#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

cmr10: \IfTFMExistsTF{cmr10}{yes}{no}

cmr42: \IfTFMExistsTF{cmr42}{yes}{no}

t5-qbkr: \IfTFMExistsTF{t5-qbkr}{yes}{no}

\end{document}



The problem is that XeTeX and LuaTeX engines provide the TeX primitive \suppressfontnotfounderror but pdfTeX doesn't.
What we can do at TeX primitive level when XeTeX or LuaTeX is used:
\suppressfontnotfounderror=1
\font\testfont=FONTNAME\relax % or use extended syntax when Unicode fonts are tested
\suppressfontnotfounderror=0
\ifx\testfont\nullfont Font FONTNAME doesn't exist\else  Font FONTNAME exists\fi

We cannot do the same with pdfTeX, unfortunately. So, only one way what to do is to fork another process with kpsewhich as shown in another answers here. Or another solution: don't use the ancient pdfTeX.
